# mysqli_fetch_array function displays none in my login page

Tags: php, mysqli

I have created Login page in php which displays ok! if Login Successfully, the validation works but fetching the data from the database fails. I mean it displays blank login page and no error reporting!

The login page code:

```
 <?php
   include 'users.php'
   if (empty ($_POST) === false) {
       $username = $_POST['uname'];
       $password = $_POST['upassword'];
       if (empty ($username) === true || empty ($password) === true){
           echo  'You need to enter a Username and Password!';
       } else if (user_exists($username) === false) {
           echo 'We can\'t find this Username. Have you registered?';
       } else{
           echo 'ok!';
           //set the user session
           //redirect the user home
       }
?>
```

the users page code:

```
<?php
function user_exists($username) {
    $query = mysqli_query(mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '',   'minepcamp'),"SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username'");
    return (mysqli_fetch_array($query));
}
?>
```

Do I need something else or am totally wrong so you correct me, thank you in advanced!

Comment: echo $query ; to check whether its returning resource?

Comment: first check database connection, second print query and execute in database

Comment: You are not validating if the users password and username combination exists. Meaning you only need the right username to enter the site

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed issues in your code.

**First:** use `mysqli_num_rows` instead of `mysqli_fetch_array`

**Second:** change `if` condition

I have add code in comments, you can use these line of code for debugging

```
function user_exists($username) {
$query = mysqli_query(mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '',   'shopdaily'),"SELECT * FROM `categories` where username = '$username'");
//$data=mysqli_num_rows($query);
return(mysqli_num_rows($query));
 //print_r($data);
}

$count=user_exists($username);
if ($count>0) {
echo "record";
}else{
    echo " no record";
}
```

As per my opinion your coding format is not good, you should use this format

```
function user_exists($username) {
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "username";
    $password = "password";
    $dbname = "myDB";

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `categories` where username = '$username'";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    return $result->num_rows;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the **mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)**.